# Вывод целого отрицательного числа в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления

Tags: c++, числа, вывод, системы-счисления

Как вывести дополнительный код hex целого отрицательного числа, вводимого в десятеричной системе счисления?

Comment: Что именно вводится-то? Положительное число, дополнительный код отрицания которого надо построить? Отрицательное число? Если отрицательное число, то в каком коде оно внутренне представлено?

Comment: Вводится число -113, на экран должно выводится его дополнительный код в hex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если число вводится именно как отрицательное, то его представление в дополнительно коде совпадает с представлением этого же числа, приведенного к беззнаковому целому типу того же размера (при этом старший бит беззнакового представления соответствует знаковому биту знакового представления)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  int i;
  std::cin >> i;

  std::make_unsigned_t<decltype(i)> u = i;
  std::cout << std::hex << u << std::endl;
}
```

---

Однако спецификация поведения `std::hex` в данном контексте и так гарантирует (гарантирует ли?), что выводимое значение будет внутренне приведено к соответствующему беззнаковому типу, поэтому можно просто

```
  int i;
  std::cin >> i;
  std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;
```

(Эта часть вызывает у меня определенные сомнения. Лучше все-таки предварительно привести самостоятельно.)

---

Если же задача подразумевает, что надо сформировать представление в дополнительном коде числа `-n` для некоего вводимого положительного числа `n`, то делается это путем инверсии всех битов числа с последующим инкрементом результата

```
  unsigned u;
  cin >> u;

  unsigned u2 = ~u + 1;
  std::cout << std::hex << u2 << std::endl;
```